# Filter Jobs by Company Size

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, filtering

I was recently looking at Jobs and wanted to exclude all really small companies.

On most job listings, the company size is listed like:

> Company size: **11-50 people**

However, there is currently no way of filtering the search results by this size.

I was basically looking to filter out all companies that fall into the 11-50 people category. I have a feeling that other users would at times want the opposite, and would want to filter out all large companies.

Can a company size filter be added, something like the below screenshot?
[image: company size filter]

Comment: I like this feature request. For many people (including me), the company size is a critical parameter.

Comment: Yes, agreed but for the opposite reason - I'm getting fed up with working for big companies.